# Stack overflow exception with reduce and union

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run following.
What I am trying to do is to divide the data in multiple parts, apply operations to each part and then join back the results.
While "take and foreach" works fine, "count" operation fails with stack overflow exception.

```
// studentTableRDD is RDD of data read from student table
// Student table contains data related to each student
val studentScoringList = studentTableRDD.map(data => data(student_id_idx)).distinct.collect.map{studentID => {studentTableRDD.filter(x => x(student_id_idx) == studentID)}}
val studentProfilingRDD = studentScoringList.map(data => scoreStudentData(1,data,trained_studentModelList)).filter(_!=null).reduce(_.union(_))

studentProfilingRDD.take(10).foreach(println(_))
studentProfilingRDD.count // throws stack overflow exception
```

Comment: where is studentProfilingRDD coming from ? .

Comment: please provide stack-trace and config you use (like `--master yarn-cluster --driver-memory 7g --executor-memory 7g`)

Comment: I think the `collect` in `.distinct.collect.map` is useless because it runs an `action` that you dont need in order to use the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `val studentScoringList = studentTableRDD.map(data => data(student_id_idx)).distinct.collect.map{studentID => {studentTableRDD.filter(x => x(student_id_idx) == studentID)}}`
   You've got List[RDD] that exactly is like source RDD. Each RDD has data for one unique studentId, and sum set of RDD equals to studentTableRDD of course. Strange at least. There is no work with data but there are one hard operation (collect) and a lot of lazy transformations. (useless splitting and computation?)
2. `val studentRDD = studentScoringList.map(data => scoreStudentData(1,data,trained_studentModelList))` transform all datum, ok (1 step is useless for a while)
3. `filter(_!=null)` if scoreStudentData can return null then something wrong with your code. Bad style. (1 step is useless for a while)
4. `reduce(_.union(_))` joins all RDD back. And again, 1 step is useless.

This code gets the same result:

```
studentTableRDD map { data => 
    val score = scoreStudentData(1,data,trained_studentModelList)
    if (score == null) None else Some(score)
} collect {
    case Some(score) => score
}
```

But I suppose that it's not your purpose.